# Can't call second function (PIC XC16)

Tags: c, pic

I'm using MPLABX XC16 on a PIC24F16KA102 and attempting to migrate from a PIC16 and mpasm.

A simple loop which sequences some LEDs should test a switch between each LED on/off and then branch out to `GoSleep` if the switch is not closed.

As far as I can see the `SwitchTest` function is never called.

```
void main(void) {
    AD1PCFG = 0xFFFF;           // All ports are digital
    TRISA = 0x0041;             // PORTA bit 0 and 6 input (port 0 = Select Button, port 6 = Wake INT) 
    __builtin_nop();
    TRISB = 0x0000;             // PORTB bit all outputs 
    __builtin_nop();
   
    while (1) {
        SwitchTest();           // if the switch is down cycle the LED's

        led_step = 0b11000001;  // and leave the last one selected on for 1 sec
        Display = led_step;     // mimic the selection in binary on LED's 5-7
        LED1 = LED_ON;          // turn on LED1 
        __delay_ms(2000);
        LED1 = LED_OFF;         // turn off LED1
        SwitchTest();
        
        led_step = 0b10100010;
        Display = led_step;
        LED2 = LED_ON;          // turn on LED2 
        __delay_ms(2000);
        LED2 = LED_OFF;         // turn off LED2
    }
}

void SwitchTest(void) 
{
    if (PORTAbits.RA0 == 0) 
    {                            // Is the Status Button pressed (low = 0)
        __delay_ms(25);
        if (PORTAbits.RA0 == 0)
        {
            return;              // Yes, resume main loop
        }
    }
    else                         // No, Sleep
    {
        GoSleep();    
    }
}
```

External pullup resistor on RA0 and pin correctly toggles when switch is pushed/released.

Attempts to debug with correctly connected PICKit failed (states bits not set correctly but doesn't show which bits) and despite running the code (in MPLABX) this PIC doesn't retain the code when the PICKit/MPLABX is disconnected and external power is applied.

Comment: Why again do you think that `SwitchTest` is never called?

Comment: The cyccling doesn't stop or continue irrespective of whether RA0 is pulled low or high.

Comment: Maybe `PORTAbits.RA0 == 0` is always true, or maybe `GoSleep();` returns?

Comment: I have just read an Errata for that PIC and it seems that there are major issues with RA0 and RB0 and other functions. Have just tested with RA1 and it seems to work. Serves me right for trying to migrate to more modern code and PICs.

Answer (score 1):

I have just read an Errata for that PIC and it seems that there are major issues with RA0 and RB0 and other functions. Have just tested with RA1 and it seems to work. Serves me right for trying to migrate to more modern code and PICs.